# Spotify: Playlist is not refreshed after adding a track via API

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am writing a script using [Spotipy](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy) that adds tracks to a Spotify playlist. 
I am using an example code from Github.

```
import pprint
import sys

import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

if len(sys.argv) > 3:
    username = sys.argv[1]
    playlist_id = sys.argv[2]
    track_ids = sys.argv[3:]
else:
    print("Usage: %s username playlist_id track_id ..." % (sys.argv[0],))
    sys.exit()

scope = 'playlist-modify-public'
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    sp.trace = False
    results = sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(username, playlist_id, track_ids)
    print(results)
else:
    print("Can't get token for", username)
```

It works fine, the track is actually added, but I need to refresh the browser to be able to play it. Is it possible to update the playlist on the fly, while it is playing so that there is no need to interrupt the music?

Comment: You could list the GitHub source maybe?

Comment: I have mentioned it in the question.
https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/examples/add_tracks_to_playlist.py

Comment: You mention that you "need to refresh the browser to be able to play it" - does this mean you're using the Spotify web player to play back tracks?

Comment: Yes, I use web player